# gotoAndPlay to a scene from a different AS3 Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am developing an adobe air AS3 game using the following scenes Structure : 
- Intro
- Game
- GameOver
I don't have any code written in the timeline, i am constantly creating AS3 Classes. The situation i'm facing is the following 
The user starts in the "Intro"scene, in which he goes to "Game" Scene. After loosing the game, he goes to "GameOver". The original fla file has a document class named : introClassToUse.as 
Once the user goes to "GameOver", he has a button to replay the game, as in go back to scene "Intro". I am using the following code for the replayGame.as :

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Screen;
    import flash.system.Capabilities;
    import flash.geom.*;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    import baseCode;
    import introClassToUse;
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class replayGame extends flash.display.MovieClip
    {

        var replayButToUse:replayBut= new replayBut();

        public function replayGame()
        {
            replayButToUse.x = 0.127 * introClassToUse.STAGE.stage.stageWidth;
            replayButToUse.y = 0.91 * introClassToUse.STAGE.stage.stageHeight;
            replayButToUse.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoIntro);
            introClassToUse.STAGE.stage.addChild(replayButToUse);
        }


        function gotoIntro(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            replayButToUse.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoIntro);
            stop();

            gotoAndPlay(1,"Intro");

            var reload:introClassToUse = new introClassToUse();




        }




    }

}
```

This code creates the replay button in "GameOver" Scene. My goal is to navigate back to "Intro" Scene once it's clicked and after navigating to that scene, re-calling the introClassToUse.as and restart the actual game. The problem is, the scene isn't found! ( the error flash cs6 shows). I'm guessing that i don't have the proper understanding of the navigation in case you are navigating from a different AS3 class. I've searched all over the internet, and tried several snippets like :

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(1,"Intro");
```

And several other internet suggestions, i always end up with the same error. How can i fix this situation?

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of what you should do:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
    // ONE frame!
    private var intro:Intro;
    private var game:Game;
    private var gameover:GameOver;
    public function Main() {
        intro=new Intro();
        game=new Game();
        gameover=new GameOver();
        // skipped
        addChild(intro);
        intro.addEventListener("startGame",startGame);
        game.addEventListener("gameOver",gameOver);
        gameover.addEventListener("backToIntro",backToIntro);
    }
    private function startGame(e:Event):void {
        if (!intro.parent) return; // sanity check
        addChild(game);
        removeChild(intro);
    }
    private function gameOver(e:Event):void {
        if (!game.parent) return;
        addChild(gameover);
        removeChild(game);
        // potentially parse the e.data to stuff "gameover" with data
    }
    private function backToIntro(e:Event):void {
        if (!gameover.parent) return;
        addChild(intro);
        removeChild(gameover);
    }
}
```

Now, code all those classes to hold whatever they need to have, and whenever the "Start game" button is pressed in intro (and the intro is ready to get removed from display list, maybe there was a transition), it does `dispatchEvent(new Event("startGame"));` and then waits until it will be added to display list again. Same for both `Game` and `GameOver` classes, with their respective events. All those classes should inherit `Sprite` at least, to both contain objects and listen to events. And look, no `gotoAndStop()` involved.

Comment: i tried your code, did the necessary changes, but my app just seems to run everything all together..i knw i am doing smthg wrong, isn't there any easier way to do so?

Comment: I doubt there's an easier way of replacing one of the core mechanics of Flash engine. But, if you do, you will have greater control of what happens within your app. The hardest thing should likely be to adapt the timeline code into your reworked timeline, as timeline code executes once the frame is created, and there is no re-creation of frames with this technqiue.

Comment: Well, I've reread your question and see you say you don't code on the timeline. Good for you. Pleas eemploy `Event. ADDED_TO_STAGE` and `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` in your nested classes, so that they would stop and start their activity when they are added and removed from the display list.

Comment: If it's only one frame, why extend `MovieClip`?

Comment: @null Technically this particular class can extend `Sprite` indeed, but if the class has something designed in Adobe Flash CS, extending Sprite is unavailable.

Comment: @Vesper I heard that as long as it is only one frame, you can use Sprite. At least for library symbols. Not sure if it also applies to document class.

Comment: @Vesper regarding this question, i've found another workaround, but can you check this question please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980900/touchevent-touch-begin-ontouchbegin-freezes-after-several-reloads

Answer (score 0):

### short answer

Do not use scenes.

### long answer

Each of the classes you have should represent a scene. Instantiate your `Intro` class and add the object to the display list: there you have your new "scene".

Add a listener to that object to wait for the event it dispatches to signal the start of the game. In the handler for that, remove the intro object from the display , instantiate the `Game` class (if you haven't already) and add that object to the display.

This is the basic idea behind how you should transition from one state of your application to another.

Comment: thank you for your answer, for this project i have to use "Long Answer". You got me a little confused since i'm really new to AS3, could you help out by giving me an example?

Comment: @Elias Rahme: the long answer is really the same as the short one, it does not use scenes either. I see if I can create a small example...

Comment: i've used another workaround regarding this question, i'll post it later on, meanwhile, could you please check this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980900/touchevent-touch-begin-ontouchbegin-freezes-after-several-reloads